# SAP HANA create table / insert into new table from select

Tags: sql, create-table, hana

How to create a new table and insert content of another table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
create column table my_new_table as
(select * from my_existing_table)
```

Comment: This is actually standard SQL, not specific to HANA. Btw: the parentheses around the `select` are not needed (and useless)

Comment: When using HANA they are needed! Also the column keyword is HANA specific

Answer (score 3):

Another, more SAP HANA specific solution is to use the

```
CREATE TABLE ... LIKE <TABLE_NAME> WITH [NO] DATA ...
```

syntax (https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/d58a5f75191014b2fe92141b7df228/content.htm#loio20d58a5f75191014b2fe92141b7df228__sql_create_table_1create_table_like_clause).

This allows more control over the physical properties of the new table.

Answer (score 1):

Like SQL Server you can create a temp table right from your select, the way is a little bit different.

Just execute:

```
temp_table = select 1 as col1, 'lorem ipsum' as col2 from dummy;
```

After that, you are able to use this temp table to query data from.

Like so:

```
select * from :temp_table;
```

[Table Variable Type Definition](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/1.0.12/en-US/ea5065d06d14426799d879234d8e3e7b.html)

Unfortunately, there is some limitations using that. For example, you cannot simply insert new data. For that, exists some tricks.